# How to make OAuth nonce in Dart

Tags: twitter, oauth, dart

Now, I make OAuth program for twitter in dart.

But, I can't make a oauth_nonce.

First, I think this code.

```dart
String create_nonce(){
    var rnd = new Random();
    int i = 0;
    var number = rnd.nextInt(pow(2,8*4));
    List<int> listi = UTF8.encode(number.toString());
    String str = "";
    while(i < 3){
        number = rnd.nextInt(pow(2,8*4)); 
        if(number < pow(2,8*4) - 1){
            number = rnd.nextInt(pow(2,8*4));
       }
       listi = UTF8.encode(number.toString());
       str = str + CryptoUtils.bytesToBase64(listi);
       i++;
    }
    return str;
}
```

But, this method can't create expected　String.

> Please tell me how to make a oauth_nonce.
>
> Nonce The oauth_nonce parameter is a unique token your application
>   should generate for each unique request. Twitter will use this value
>   to determine whether a request has been submitted multiple times. The
>   value for this request was generated by base64 encoding 32 bytes of
>   random data, and stripping out all non-word characters, but any
>   approach which produces a relatively random alphanumeric string should
>   be OK here.
>
> oauth_nonce   kYjzVBB8Y0ZFabxSWbWovY3uYSQ2pTgmZeNu2VS4cg

Comment: Please give more information. For example what you have tried so far and what is not working as expected.

Comment: Did you port this code from somewhere else? Do you have a link to the original? Any error message or information how the expected String should look like and how it actually looks?

Comment: This method return String included unacceptable　 letter, "=". This method is thought by me.

Comment: Any link to a description or requirements what create_nounce should do?

Comment: [this page](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/authorizing-request) has a description about oauth_nonce.

Comment: I added the part I think applies to your question. Please approve if this is what you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```dart
import 'dart:math' as math;
import 'package:crypto/crypto.dart';


void main() {
  math.Random rnd = new math.Random();

  List<int> values = new List<int>.generate(32, (i) => rnd.nextInt(256));
  print(CryptoUtils.bytesToBase64(values));
}
```

produces

> QqPlpI8BmDk9byWDqJ4tBCMMIWv24v4WL5KZsufnWqQ=

I'm not sure what this means exactly

> and stripping out all non-word characters

I found https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/12445

> You just want to make sure you're not sending characters like "!" "#" or "$" in your oauth_nonce. The process you've suggested sounds like it would work just fine.

.

> Base64 includes '+' and '/'. You may need to stripping out them since they are non-word characters.

this should do it

```dart
import 'dart:math' as math;
import 'package:crypto/crypto.dart';

void main() {
  math.Random rnd = new math.Random();

  List<int> values = new List<int>.generate(32, (i) => rnd.nextInt(256));
  print(CryptoUtils.bytesToBase64(values).replaceAll(new RegExp('[=/+]'), ''));
}
```

out before and after `replaceAll`

> elrA+4rWr4O3zNv0L57iOLqTQD94abJ23hFoK+hk6QE=
>   elrA4rWr4O3zNv0L57iOLqTQD94abJ23hFoKhk6QE

Comment: I can make oauth_nonce using this method. Thank you very much

Comment: So this is what you wanted? Great!

Comment: `CryptoUtils.bytesToBase64` is now deprecated and should be replaced by `base64UrlEncode` from the package `dart:convert` => `import 'dart:convert';`

Answer (score 0):

There is a package for that. It's generate nonce automaticaly:
https://pub.dev/packages/nonce